# $a$ point is chosen randomly in $[0,5]$, $b$ is chosen randomly from $[1,6]$. Find $P(\int_\sqrt{b}^a xdx>\frac{3}{2})$?

Tags: probability

$a$ point is chosen randomly from $[0,5]$, $b$ is chosen randomly from $[1,6]$.

Find $P(\int_\sqrt{b}^a xdx>\frac{3}{2})$ ?

$P(\frac{x^2}{2}|_\sqrt{b}^a>\frac{3}{2})=P(\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{b}{2}>\frac{3}{2}).$

Then $\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{b}{2}>\frac{3}{2} \implies b<(a-\sqrt{3})(a+\sqrt{3}) \implies 1<(a-\sqrt{3})(a+\sqrt{3})<6 $ since ($b\in [1,6]$) $\implies 2<a<3$.

Since $a\in [0,5]$ the probablity it is chosen when $2<a<3$ is $\frac{1}{5} $
but this is a wrong answer.

Where am I wrong ?

Help please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $a$ and $b$ are randomly chosen and considering independently chosen, $A \sim U(0, 5)$ and $B \sim U(1, 6)$.

Given $a^2 - b \gt 3$, yes we must have $a \gt 2$. But it is not correct that $a \lt 3$. For $2 \lt a \lt 3, 1 \lt b \lt a^2 - 3$ and for $a \gt 3$, any value of $b \in (1, 6)$ satisfies the condition.

So, $~ \displaystyle P(a^2 - b \gt 3) = \int_2^3 \int_1^{a^2-3} \frac{1}{25} ~db ~ da ~ +$
$ \displaystyle \int_3^5 \int_1^6 \frac{1}{25} ~db ~ da ~$

Or it is easier to see that for any value of $b$, we must have $a \gt \sqrt{b+3}$

So $\displaystyle P(a^2 - b \gt 3) = \int_1^6 \int_{\sqrt{b+3}}^5 \frac{1}{25} ~ da ~ db$

---

See if the diagram showing support of $a$ and $b$ helps. To the left of the parabola curve, $a^2 - b \lt  3$ and to its right, $a^2 - b \gt 3$. We need to find the probability that $a$ and $b$ are chosen in the region shaded in dark grey, which is to the right of parabola.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate! Thanks!